# Free TObjectList declared as TList

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

How should the list (and its objects) declared as

```
var 
   myList: TList;
```

and created as

```
myList := TObjectList.Create;
```

be freed?

Should the objects be freed separately in a loop, as in a simple `TList`, or will `myList.Free` also free the objects in the list, since it was created as `TObjectList`?

Comment: Yes, the TObjectList dtor will be called.

Answer (score 4):

The advantage of `TObjectList` over the regular `TList` is that if the [`TObjectList.OwnsObjects`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Contnrs.TObjectList.OwnsObjects) property is set to true then it means that the `TObjectList` is maintaining the lifetime of the objects that have been added to it.

Quote from the [`TObjectList`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Contnrs.TObjectList) documentation:

> Use TObjectList to store and maintain a list of objects. TObjectList
> provides properties and methods to add, delete, rearrange, locate,
> access, and sort objects. If the OwnsObjects property is set to true
> (the default), TObjectList controls the memory of its objects, freeing
> an object when its index is reassigned; when it is removed from the
> list with the Delete, Remove, or Clear method; or when the TObjectList
> instance is itself destroyed.

So, if you set your `TObjectList` to own its objects (which is its default behavior), upon its destruction it will automatically destroy each object in its list.

The exception would be if you are using a Delphi version with **Advanced Reference Counting** for objects <sup>1</sup>. The `TObjectList` would only reduce the reference count for the objects that it owns. So, if such objects are also referenced somewhere else, they would not be destroyed until those additional references are also removed.

<sup>1</sup>: object ARC was used only for iOS and Android platforms. It was first introduced in Delphi XE4, but later removed in Delphi 10.4 Sydney, unifying the traditional object memory management model on all platforms.

Comment: Note the question is tagged [tag:delphi-2010], ARC doesn't apply in that version.

Comment: @RemyLebeau True. But for sake of completion of the answer which might be as well seen by other users that are using different versions of Delphi I still included that information in the answer. Now I don't have detailed information of which Delphi versions and on which platforms was ARC being used at hand. If you do feel free to edit my answer by adding that information to it.

Comment: I added the info